# Multiple pull requests on Bitbucket using Mercurial

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I know how to create multiple pull requests from one fork on GitHub: you create separate branches for each PR.

How to do the same using Mercurial on Bitbucket? Do I need to create 'bookmarks' or 'multiple heads'? I have already created one PR from default, now I want to add a second PR that doesn't depend on the new commits on my default. In git, I would do the following:

```
$ git branch -b new-patch HEAD~
```

Then do commits, and

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin new-patch
```

after which I can create a PR from the new branch `new-patch`.

How to do the same with Mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial is simpler there:

Checkout the changeset you want to see your changes based-on and simply start writing and commiting. When done programming, push.